# WooCommerce widget "WooCommerce Products" template

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

There is a task to display on the main page two widgets "WooCommerce Products", the problem is that they have a completely different design. I overwritten the "content-widget-product.php" file in my theme, everything is fine with the first widget, but what should I do to create a template for the second widget?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should write a new widget that matches the required design